# Random ball under cup game in Python

Tags: python

```
def talon_game():
mylist = ['1', '2', '3'] 
keep_playing = True

while keep_playing:

    print "\nThere are 3 cups, and 1 egg hidden underneath."
    print "Which cup do you think the egg is under?\n"

    talong_c = raw_input("1 - 2 - 3? ")

    while talong_c not in "123":

        talong_c = raw_input("1 - 2 - 3? ")

    true_cup = random.choice(mylist)
    if talong_c == true_cup:
        print "\nYou win!"
        print "Would you like to play again?\n"
        talong_c1 = raw_input("> ")
        keep_playing = 'yes' in talong_c1.lower()
    elif talong_c1 != 'yes': #added this as one example, but nothing has worked obviously
        keep_playing = False
    else:
        print "\nYou lose!  It was under cup", true_cup
        print "Would you like to play again?\n"
        talong_c1 = raw_input("> ")
        keep_playing = 'yes' in talong_c1.lower()
```

Additional coded noted by a #
Not sure what happens when keep_playing is False other than the program ending
Now I'm just adding details so it will let me post this as I explained most of it below

Comment: "if talong_c == "1" and randomchoice(mylist) == "1":"  -> punctation missing -> random POINT choice(mylist). If it isn't working after changing: post the complete error message (with lines and co.)!

Comment: Recursion is not a good looping strategy.  Instead, you should make a top-level "while" loop that continues so long as the input is "yes".  Similarly, the "input grabbers" would be while loops that continue until they get valid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clean up the loop structures a bit:

1. When you need input, set up a while loop that continues until you
   get it.
2. When you want to keep playing the game, do it in a loop as
   long as the player enters some form of "yes".
3. Recursion puts bad karma on the run-time stack.
4. Simplify the input checking.

...

```
import random

mylist = [1, 2, 3]
keep_playing = True

while keep_playing:

    # Get legal guess
    print "There are 3 cups, and 1 egg hidden underneath."
    print "Which cup do you think the egg is under?"
    talong_c = raw_input("1 - 2 - 3? ")
    while talong_c not in "123":
        talong_c = raw_input("1 - 2 - 3? ")

    true_cup = random.choice(mylist)
    if int(talong_c) == true_cup:
        print "\nYou win!"
    else:
        print "\nYou lose!  It was under cup", true_cup

    print "Would you like to play again?"
    talong_c1 = raw_input("> ")
    keep_playing = talong_c1.lower() == 'y'
```

You still have to adapt this to your high-level game control, insert your other two routines, and get a few usable variable names, but this should get you started well.

Comment: Holy cow I totally forgot about while loops. Thanks for the clear and concise answer! Have a busy day but will get cracking at this later.

Comment: Remember to "accept" one of the answers once you've had time to evaluate them all; this properly resolves the question in the SO data base.

Comment: I cannot get this to run at all. It just loops the first two print lines forever..

Comment: Then you've entered something improperly: the third line prints a prompt and waits for input.  Also, I'm about to update the code to be a self-contained example, and fixed a couple of edge problems.

Comment: I still cannot get it to run as you've typed it, but edited my question at the top to show code that does work for me. The only thing I'm confused about now (I think, ha) is the keep_playing part at the end. That part doesn't do what it's supposed to for me.

Comment: You're not testing "keep_playing".  See my example.  You're still stuck on right/wrong guess.

Comment: Ok. Indentation issues. Running now. Loop works with y, but with any other input just kills the program.

Comment: That _is_ the idea: Anything that starts with 'y' keeps going; any other entry exits.  See my point #2 ?

Comment: For the actual game (outside of the 3 cup game), what is the procedure to get anything other than a 'y' answer to go back to the main game? I obviously do not understand loops... Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You fall out of the bottom of this subroutine.  That automatically returns to whatever module called this one.

Comment: When I put the code into the main game, anything other than 'y' doesn't fall out of the subroutine, it just kills the entire program.

Comment: That subroutine *is* the entire program.  :-)  This doesn't "kill" the program; the program ends naturally by running out of statements.

What functionality did you want, and what else have you tried to get it?

Comment: I want to have any answer with 'no' exit out of this function and go back to a previous one. Also have any answer that isn't 'yes or no' bring up a print statement, then ask the 'play again' question again. I've tried adding other if statements but the whole looping thing still confuses me. Example code in original question

Comment: Got it.  Unfortunately, tutoring you on the concept of a loop is well beyond the range of StackOverflow.  I recommend that you go back to your class materials and/or on-line tutorial information and work through all the examples.  Get pencil and paper and step through each looping example, one statement at a time, tracking variable values as you go.  When you get the idea a little bit, replace this by running the loop in your Python environment, adding print statements to track the values for you.

If you still can't get this, you might try starting a chat and adding me.

Comment: Will do. Need to wrap my head around loops obviously! Thanks for your help. I don't have enough 'reputation' to chat yet, but thanks for the offer!

Answer (score 1):

What is your question exactly?

Regarding random.choice(), maybe you need something like:

```
mylist = ['1', '2', '3']   # Since input will be a string, not an int.
answer = random.choice(mylist)
```

followed later by

```
if talong_c == answer:
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this along with the answer below when I have time later today.